# (Python) One variable becomes zero while assigning the value to another variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

As the title say, one variable is causing another to become zero for no apparent reason. Here is my code, shorted with a ton of print statements trying to figure out what's going on.

```
for i in range(1, number_of_layers):
    a_nt[i] = 0.5 * ((dia / 2) ** 2) * (theta_t[i] - sin(theta_t[i]))
    print("ant 1 ", a_nt[i])
```

I assign a value to a_nt and later decide how that value will be used in an if state to assign it to a_t. The code goes into the else portion.

```
else:
    print("ant 2 ", a_nt[i])
    a_t[i] = a_nt[i]
    print("at 1 ", a_t[i])
    y_t[i] = y_nt[i]
    print("at 2 ", a_t[i])
    theta_c[i] = 0
    print("at 3 ", a_t[i])
```

Python prints out:

ant 1  0.005738905060148785

ant 2  0.005738905060148785

at 1  0.005738905060148785

at 2  0.005738905060148785

at 3  0

For a reason that I cannot determine, a_t becomes zero after I assign theta_c a value of zero. I'm relatively new to python, but this is driving me insane!

Comment: Are you multiplying a value by 0?

Comment: No, I set theta_c[i] to zero and a_t becomes zero. There aren't connected to each other.

Comment: Are you doing something like `some_varaible = some_list` in your code somewhere?

Comment: Specifically, are you doing something equivalent to: `theta_c = a_t`?

Comment: That was it, thank you!

Comment: @AndrewGulbronson Great! I added an answer to clarify; if that solved your problem you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make an assignment like `theta_c = a_t`, then you're not actually copying the array, you're merely referencing the same array with another variable.

Thus, when you change `theta_c`, you're also changing `a_t`. You should be probably taking a shallow copy instead:

```
theta_c = list(a_t)
```

Of course, depending on the situation, even a shallow copy may not be sufficient, but in this case it will probably do the trick.